# Iniciar un JComboBox con un valor iniciado anteriormente

Tags: java, combobox

Buen día, quisiera iniciar un JComboBox con un valor elegido anteriormente, es decir, que guarde el valor seleccionado en un jdialog y luego, cuando inicio nuevamente ese jdialog aparezca seleccionado por defecto el valor elegido antes.

Este es mi jdialog:

```
public class Opciones extends javax.swing.JDialog {

Datos_Informe dt;
JTextField campo;
String obser;
JTable tabla;
int seleccion;


public Opciones(Principal parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    principal = parent;
    initComponents();
    rellenarComboBox();
    java.util.Date hoy = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat formateador = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    txt_emision.setText(formateador.format(hoy));
    tabla = principal.getTabla();
    txt_cant_muest.setText(this.cantMuestras());

}
public void rellenarComboBox() {

    ArrayList<String[]> empresas = Otras.empresasOpciones();

    for (String[] datos : empresas) {

        jComboBox1.addItem(datos[0]);

    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Opciones dialog = new Opciones((Principal) new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
                dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    Principal principal;
```

Y mi clase principal llama al jdialog Opciones de esta forma:

```
public class Principal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private TableModel modelo;

public Principal() {
    initComponents();
    setTitle("Laboratorio 3.0");
    Otras.colocarColumnas(jTable1);

}
private void generar_informeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        this.setTabla(jTable1);
        Opciones opciones = new Opciones(this, true);

        opciones.setVisible(rootPaneCheckingEnabled);
    }
```

}

Estuve probando con clases getter y setter tratando de obtener el valor index del combobox para luego usarlo en el constructor del jdialog pero no estaria funcionando, siempre inicia el jcombobox en el primer valor

Comment: Tendrás que guardar el item seleccionado antes de abrir el diálogo y seleccionarlo al volver: `getSelectedItem` y `setSelectedItem`

Comment: Podrias crear una variable miembro en el marco o ventana padre y pasarsele el marco por parametro con un metodo setter y getter para que se guarde el valor en la ventana padre y asi cuando abras el jdialog el valor este guardado en la ventana padre. Disculpa, pero es lo unico que se me ocurre, ojala te resulte.